# Changing actionbar properties from styles.xml has no effect

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to change the background colour and shadow of the actionbar from the xml but it has no effect.

What am i doing wrong?

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/Red</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/Red</item>
         <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@color/Green</item>
    </style>
```

Menifest

```
    <application
        android:name="Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidDevelopers" >
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

create your custom actionbar using this tool
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=dark&actionbarstyle=transparent&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100

and your custom style in your manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/your theme name" >
```